# Error: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to fill the matrix A with  the numbers obtained from the numerical integration of I.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.ones((10,10))

for x0 in np.arange(0, 1, 0.1):
     for y0 in np.arange(0, 1, 0.1):
            s = np.arange(0, 16, 0.1)  
            I = ((y0*np.cos(s*np.exp(0.5*y0**2 - 0.5*(x0 - 1)**2))))
            i = x0*10                      
            j = y0*10
            A[i, j] = np.trapz(I,s)

print(A)
```